# How get model's table name in October Cms static?

Tags: laravel, octobercms

My plugin code:

```
public function boot()
    {
        **I can:**
        $user = new User();
        $table = $user->getTable();
        **I would like to:**
        echo User::getTable();
        exit;
        $user = $this->user;

        \Serviom\Guestpage\Models\Post::extend(function($model) use ($user) {
            $model->rules = [
                'name' => 'required|between:3,100',
                'subject' => 'required|between:3,100',
                'desc' => 'required|between:10,1000',
                'parent_id' => 'nullable|exists:serviom_guestpage_posts,id',
                'user_id' => 'nullable|exists:' . $table . ',id',
```

Comment: This might help : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1436

Comment: There are no decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Variable in modal `$table` is protected member so its really nothing we can do about that but we can simply access it by adding public method to class [ extend it ]

> In any of your plugin you can add this snippet

```php
use RainLab\User\Models\User as UserModel;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function boot() {

      UserModel::extend(function($model) {
          $model->addDynamicMethod('getTableName', function() use ($model) {
              return $model->getTable();
          });
      });

     //....
```

> Now you can able to call

```php
echo User::getTableName();
```

Its like kind of `hack` but **its only if you really badly needed it** then you do something like this

if any doubt please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static method to your Model as a helper :

```
class MyModel extends Model
{

    public static function getTableName()
    {
        return with(new static)->getTable();
    }

}
```

Usage : `MyModel::getTableName()`

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1436#issuecomment-18618393)